# R eval in function: object 'x' not found

Tags: r, eval

I am trying to evaluate an R expression in a function:

```
test <- function(x, expr) {
  env <- new.env()
  env$x <- x
  eval(expr, envir=env)
}

test(iris, expr={ cor(x) })
```

But I get: Error in is.data.frame(x) : Object `x` not found.

The error is due to `x` being unknown when `cor(x)` is evaluated. Since I am evaluating the expression with `env`, I would have expected `x` to be known during the evaluation of the expression.

I tried some other functions like `with` or `local` and so on, but got the same result.

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're expecting to happen. Are you trying to use `x` as a placeholder for whatever `x=` resolves to inside the function? For that to work, I would expect `cor(iris)` to work on the console (it does not). However, I can do `test <- function(x, expr) { expr <- substitute(expr); eval(expr, envir = x); }; test(iris, expr={ cor(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) });`.

Comment: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html might be helpful when learning/debugging non-standard evaluation (NSE), if that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way to do this is `test(iris[, 1:4], quote(cor(x)))`; you need to (1) include only numeric columns of `iris` (otherwise you'll get an "'x' must be numeric" error) and (2) use `quote()` to prevent R from evaluating `cor(x)` before you want.  As @r2evans points out, the other way to do this is

```r
test <- function(x, expr) {
  env <- new.env()
  env$x <- x
  eval(substitute(expr), envir=env)
}
test(iris[, 1:4], cor(x))
```